# Do we apply DRY principle only to the state of the object or also to its behavior?

Tags: design-patterns, dry

I'm struggling to understand DRY principle

1) I know purpose of DRY principle is to avoid duplication/repetition of information, but what does the term `information` refer to in the context of DRY? Does it refer only to `the state of the object` ( ie `Person` entity should only have a single property representing its `birth data` ) or does the term also refer to `behavior of the object` (  ie. `Dog` entity should only have one method representing `barking behavior`  )

2) Question assumes the term `information` also refers to a `behavior`:

DRY is all about not repeating the same information, which I interpret as *we shouldn't have two or more methods/code snippets doing the exactly same thing*. But I assume the term `repetition` is used more loosely in the context of DRY? Namely, I've seen examples where DRY was also applied to methods/code snippets that have **similar** behavior ( thus these methods/code snippets didn't do exactly the same thing ) and yet these methods/code snippets were then replaced with a single method/code snippet?!

Thank you

Comment: `Don't Repeat Yourself`-  Don't forget about the **Yourself** part.  Any time you start to type something that you've already typed, your DRY alarm bells should at least give a warning chime.  It's not really about state or functionality, it's about CODE repetition.

Comment: @Floegipoky: "It's not really about state or functionality" If two different classes contain same state, but each of these two states is acquired using very different logic, or if two classes contain two methods with same behavior, but these two behaviors are represented with two very different algorithms, then according to you that is not a violation of DRY?

Comment: No, you're forgetting about the `Yourself` part again.  DRY isn't a set-in-stone Law of Programming, it's a rule of thumb that somebody came up with when they realized how many problems duplication tends to cause.  Don't go looking for a definition that covers all of its nuances.  Like so many other software engineering terms, it's really just a description of a particular code smell.  Code can be duplicated verbatim, or at the design level.  The two attempts at counter-examples in your comment are examples of the latter, and this type tends to be more difficult to spot.

Comment: @Floegipoky: So code duplicated at design level is also a violation of DRY?

Comment: Usually, yes.  Like I said, don't go looking for a definition of DRY, look to understand the problems that motivated the creation of a label for it.  These problems mostly involve the added complexity of having to keep multiple similar pieces of code up to date.  Some people apply it to literally everything involved in the development process, including documentation, boilerplate code, etc.  Everybody has their own working definition; the important thing is to think about how YOU (there's that **Yourself** bit again) can use the principle of avoiding duplication to create better software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) "information" refers to any piece of **code**:

- from a large code snippet (manually calculating the square root of a number all over the place should be replaced with a Sqrt method)
- to a simple value (using the string "Monday" all over the place, should be replaced with an enumeration of the days in a week).

2) If two methods are *similar*, then one can argue that some parts of it do the exact same thing. If that's the case, and if it's feasible to generalize the logic in those two methods to solve a generic problem, instead of two specific problems, then they should be refactored in order to comply with the DRY principle.

If it's not feasible to generalize the whole algorithm, then consider at least refactoring the parts that do the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0):

The DRY principal exists primarily to make enhancement and maintenance easier. The idea being that every time a duplication is introduced maintainability and extensibility goes down. Here are two examples:

### Duplicated Code

```
public class Dog {

    int barkCount = 0;

    public void bark(){
        println "bark";
        barkCount++;
    }

    public void defendHouse(){
        println "bark";
        barkCount++;
        println "run in circles";
    }

}
```

While this example is somewhat primitive, you'll see that the logic in bark is duplicated in defendHouse. This is undesirable for several reasons:

- The code is harder to read (longer, more parts, developer has to notice duplication)
- The code is harder to maintain (a developer may forget to update defendHouse() logic when they update bark() logic.)

Both of these bullet points are big considerations in long lived software (Hint: all software is long lived) because they are recurring costs that are incurred with each change/read. This is even worse if the duplication happens over greater distances-- duplicated logic may be in different files or packages for example.

### Duplicated Data

```
public class Person {
    String birthDay = null;
    Date birthDate = null;

    public void setBirthDate(Date newDate){
        birthDate = newDate;
        birthDay = newDate.getDayOfWeek();
    }

    public void clearBirthDate(){
        birthDate = null;
        birthDay = null;
    }

    public String getBirthDay(){
        if(newDate == null){
            return null;
        } else {
            return newDate.getDayOfWeek();
        }
    }
}
```

The issue here is that the birthDay is a subset of birthDate. The biggest issues here are:

- Data integrity: a developer may fail to update one field when another field changes. It can be difficult to guarantee consistency (for example, if newDate.getDayOfWeek() throws an exception then the fields may get out of sync).
- Readability: This code is harder to read because a developer has to notice that birthDay and birthDate are associated (but only by convention).

For the sake of completeness, here are the two examples improved and my thoughts on when to violate the DRY principal...

### Cleaned up: Duplicated Code

```
public class Dog {

    int barkCount = 0;

    public void bark(){
        println "bark";
        barkCount++;
    }

    public void defendHouse(){
        bark();
        println "run in circles";
    }

}
```

### Cleaned up: Duplicated Data

```
public class Person {
    Date birthDate = null;

    public void setBirthDate(Date newDate){
        birthDate = newDate;
    }

    public void clearBirthDate(){
        birthDate = null;
    }

    public String getBirthDay(){
        if(newDate == null){
            return null;
        } else {
            return newDate.getDayOfWeek();
        }
    }

}
```

### Additional Thoughts

So when is it okay to duplicate code/data? This section is going to be heavily based on my experiences/opinions, so be ready to disagree.

- For very simple code (like simple expressions) duplication may be acceptable. This is only true if the expression is trivial to read, hard to get wrong, and not easily grouped with some logical entity nearby.
- When the language doesn't support abstractions to remove the duplication. For example, because Java doesn't have closures it can be wearying to remove duplication from comparators and other 'function-objects'. Certain kinds of duplication are common as a result.
- Once a performance issue has been experienced data duplication may be needed to speed things up.
- You don't have enough time to get it 'just right'. This point is really more about picking your battles. Some kinds of duplication are more hazardous than others. Often times, a change in requirements can force duplication into a well designed system. The only fix may be expensive. In these circumstances it makes sense to talk to your team/managers and decide how important the fix is.